# Definite Integrals and Average Temperature

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Here is a problem:

Suppose that at the beginning of day 0, some time last summer, the temperature in Boston was `y(0) = 15◦` Celsius and that over a 50-day period, the temperature increased according to the rule `y'(t) = y(t)/50`, with time t measured in days. Find the formula for y.  By definition, day 0 is `0 < t < 1`.  Find the average temperature on day 3.  Find the average on day 4.

Is this correct for the formula for y:  `y(t) = 15 + t`

And then is the average for day 3 the definite integral of that function with limits from 0 to 3?

Comment: You should always test to see if your suggested solution fits the differential equation. If $y_p(t) = 15 + t$, then $y'_p(t) = 1 \neq y_p(t)/50$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain an expression for $y$, you have to solve the differential equation : $$y' = \frac{y}{50}$$
It is a first order linear equation so the solution is of the form : $$y(t)=Ke^{\frac{1}{50}t}, K \in \mathbb{R}$$
And with condition $y(0)=15$ you should be able to find the correct value of $K$.
Can you continue from there ?

And the average for day $3$, is the integral on $[2,3]$, the integral from $0$ to $3$ would be the average on the days $1,2$ and $3$.

Comment: So is the formula y(t) = 15e^t/50?

Comment: yes that's it :)

Comment: And is the average for day 3 the integral of 15e^3/50 from limits 2 to 3?

Comment: yes that's it;;

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question before reading this, it's a question from the 18.01 problem set 5, while I got some memories after reading Bérénice's answer.  It surely provided some hints before this question, like the radioactive decay and object's temperature change and Newton's law of cooling. I suppose we should really learn the soul of math when solving questions and not just solving the questions (unfortunately I'm the later one).

For this question, we can think it this way, $y' = \frac{y(t)}{50}$ suggest that the function's derivative is a fraction of the original function, and as what we learned from previous materials, only function $y = e^x$ meet such condition, then chain rule will help us build the function $f(x) = e^\frac{x}{50}$.

But where does that $K$ comes from Bérénice's answer?  It turns out it comes from separation of variables, we have $y' = \frac{y(t)}{50}$ which can be written as $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{y}{100}$ or $\frac{dy}{dy} = \frac{dt}{100}$ then $\int\frac{dy}{dy} = \int\frac{dt}{100}$ gives us $ln(y) = \frac{t}{100} + c$ or $y = e^{\frac{t}{100}+c}$ or $y = Ke^{\frac{t}{100}}$.  And then you have your answers as Bérénice already posted.

But I think knowing how to think matters more, hence I post the above comments here.  I hope it's helpful.